# How do I switch arrow types on the PC?

Tags: pc, far-cry-4

So far I only found some youtube video about it, where you can't really see what key-combination the guy is pressing.

So how do you switch arrow types on the pc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hold the key you want to switch weapon (ie.: <kbd>Q</kbd>) then press <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>E</kbd> to select the special arrow type.

[image]

Comment: For those of us who have remapped their keys, what are `R` and `E` bound to by default? **Reload** and **Interact/Use**?

Comment: @DavidHarkness Yes, exactly. I'm surprised the game doesn't show the right keys once remapped. You can see this menu holding the weapon selection key (`Q` or numbers from 1 to 5 by default)

Comment: These are some highly annoying key bindings. With my mapping, I need to do some contorted finger combos to get them.